# How to select the minimum value within a group that maximizes another value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, row-number

I am working with a table similar to the following:

| week | Time | Person | Direction | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00 | A | 27 | 4 |
| 1 | 12:00 | A | 27 | 6 |
| 1 | 12:00 | A | 27 | 8 |
| 1 | 12:00 | B | 20 | 2 |
| 1 | 12:00 | B | 20 | 5 |
| 1 | 12:00 | B | 20 | 7 |
| 1 | 12:00 | C | 17 | 3 |
| 1 | 12:00 | C | 17 | 4 |
| 1 | 12:00 | C | 17 | 6 |
| 1 | 1:00 | A | 3 | 9 |
| 1 | 1:00 | A | 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 1:00 | A | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 1:00 | B | 6 | 3 |
| 1 | 1:00 | B | 6 | 4 |
| 1 | 1:00 | B | 6 | 8 |
| 1 | 1:00 | C | 12 | 10 |
| 1 | 1:00 | C | 12 | 9 |
| 1 | 1:00 | C | 12 | 14 |

As you can see, within each value of `Time` there are multiple observations for each `Person`. Every person has the same value of `Direction` in all their observations at a given time, but different values of `Distance`. For each value of `Time` I want to select only observation with the smallest `Distance` for the person who maximizes `Direction`.

I also want to create columns for the person with second highest `Direction` value and their minimum `Distance.`

So for each value of time I will only return one observation. Here's what I want to return:

| week | Time | max_direction_person | max_person_min_distance | second_max_direction_person | second_max_person_min_distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00 | A | 4 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 1:00 | C | 9 | B | 3 |

How is this possible? I have tried group by subqueries, but haven't had any success.

Comment: How should ties be handled?

Comment: @DanGuzman As long as the data is uniform (1 row per observation, same number of columns) it doesn't really matter to me who is labeled first and second if they're tied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this. `DENSE_RANK` will identify the ordering of each set of `Person` rows, and then `ROW_NUMBER` can number within those sets.

Then you filter to the rows which have a dense-rank of 1 or 2, and a row-number of 1, and simply pivot it using `MIN` or `MAX` to get a grouped result per `Time`.

```sql
WITH Maxed AS (
    SELECT *,
      dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Week, Time ORDER BY Direction DESC),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Week, Time, Direction, Person ORDER BY Distance ASC)
    FROM Observation o
)
SELECT
  Week,
  Time,
  max_direction_person           = MIN(CASE WHEN dr = 1 THEN Person END),
  max_person_min_distance        = MIN(CASE WHEN dr = 1 AND rn = 1 THEN Distance END),
  second_max_direction_person    = MIN(CASE WHEN dr = 2 THEN Person END),
  second_max_person_min_distance = MIN(CASE WHEN dr = 2 AND rn = 1 THEN Distance END)
FROM Maxed
WHERE dr >= 1 AND dr <= 2
  AND rn = 1
GROUP BY
  Week,
  Time;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/XOMv0H-B)

Note that the addition of `Direction` in the `ROW_NUMBER` partitioning is technically unnecessary, however it will be more efficient due to the existing sort for the `DENSE_RANK` calculation.